# Difficulty in Storing Different sorts of Z3 expr into a map

Tags: z3

I created a std::map of z3::expr and int pair, and wanted to store different expressions. However, when I was storing expression of different kinds, say **first a 64-bit vector and then a 32-bit vector**, compilers throwed a **z3::exception** and  complaining **invalid function application for bvslt, sort mismatch on argument at position 2, expected (_ BitVec 64) but given (_ BitVec 32)**. It wont complain if I store expr with 64bitvec only or 32 bitvec only. I don't know how this bvslt comes from in storing two independent expressions.

So my question is that is there any way I can store expr with different sorts into a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can store expressions of different sorts. 
Based on your description you are running into a C++ overloading "experience".
THe operator < is overloaded to exprs. Instead you want to use comparison on expressions as abstract syntax trees. The expressions expose a unique identifier, which is an unsigned. You want to declare your std::map template by passing in comparison operator on those identities. This is typically done by declaring a helper struct or class. Since you are already using C++ I presume you know how to do this :-).

Comment: I created a struct comparing hash of the two exprs and it works. Please let me know if you have any better comparing criteria